# hCaptcha not loading up at all in China #1

Tags: recaptcha

hCaptcha is not loading up at all in China. Any help? I have tried Head Editor, Gooreplacer on Chrome, Firefox and Edge, no luck!

[image]

Comment: This is the site that i'm using: https://www.epicnpc.com/login/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting-like questions are off-topic in Web Applications. You might try one of the sites about using computers like [su], [apple.se], [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], etc. You can find the complete list of [se] sites on https://stackexchange.com/sites